# Is it possible connect USB DRIVE to iPhone (using data cable and EAAccessory)?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, usb, usb-drive

Is it possible connect USB FLASH DRIVE to iPhone cable and onIphone reading data from this drive ?

thanks,

Comment: It appears that he's asking about the possibility of connecting to this via the External Accessory framework, so it's not just a hardware question.

Comment: No. Without jailBreaks ! On legal iPhones...

Comment: Guys, why it is off topic? I've asked about possibility of Framework from iOS SDK EAAccessory to provide API, events, etc to connect via 30 pin connector. Thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only devices in the Made for iPod program can communicate to the iPhone via the 30-pin dock connector.  These devices also need to publish a protocol for applications to access them via the External Accessory framework.  Generic USB storage devices will not satisfy this, and I know of no Made for iPod accessories that either are USB storage devices or allow access to them.

Answer (score 1):

Only if that USB Flash drive was designed to be an iPod/iPhone accessory.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by modifying your iphone USB cable and adding a 10 ohms resister on the positive of the data transfer pin on the 30 pin iphone dock cable, the 10 ohms resister should be added to pin 27 on the 30 pin dock cable ( remember that the pin 30 is really pin 1 and pin 1 is 30. Why that is, is beyond me but it can complicate the modification ) and also modifying the USB end of your iPhone cable to a female, enabling to recieve a USB stick or flash drive.